# Issues with forms submission on single HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a few forms in a single HTML page, and the main idea is that these form submissions are independent from each other and employ AJAX to prevent a full page reload.

[image]

This means that the search segment is a form, and after the search is successfully completed (using AJAX), each search result is displayed as a card containing another form with a single field for bids.

Strangely, even though I try to employ the same technique for the bid addition as I did for the search, the page refreshes every time I submit a bid, and the request becomes part of the URL:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
  <!-- Card display: cards are generated dynamically -->
  <div id="card-container">
  </div>
```

Here is my JavaScript (and JQuery) for this particular form:

```
var bidReq;

$("#add-bid").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log("entered form");

  if (bidReq) {
    bidReq.abort();
  }
  $form = $("this");

  // Serialize data in the form
  var serialized = $("form").serialize();

  // Fire off the request to php/add_bid.php
  bidReq = $.post (
    "php/add_bid.php",
    serialized,
    disableAddBidButtons
  );
});

function disableAddBidButtons(response) {
    console.log("bye");
}
```

I suspect that it might be because `$_POST` is a global variable that currently still stores the information for the individual cards, but I am really not very sure about this. The full HTML, CSS and JavaScript can be found here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLXPaM

I have included a description of the HTML for the dynamically generated card in the HTML file as well.

I read that having multiple forms in a single HTML page is not exactly good practice, so if you have a better idea, please let me know as well!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `$("this")` should be `$(this)`, and `$("form").serialize();` => `$form.serialize()`

Comment: @TryingToImprove Hmm I just tried that, and the issue is persisting. I even made sure that the JS file has been updated by viewing the page source. Also, if this was the issue, the URL would probably not have been able to receive the input anyway...? And my first form (search) would have failed..? Thanks anyway for the feedback!

Comment: Bind the event listener after loading the cards, or try `$("#card-container").on('submit', '#add-bid', function(event)`

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden your solution worked! I am just so bewildered though, and cannot see why that should work when my current implementation does not. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind your event listener to a non-existing element (because you load the form later after a search):

```
$("#add-bid").submit(function(event) {
```

Here, the `#add-bid` form doesn't exists.

You can add and remove the event listener after you added the element, so after each search.

A better way would be to bind the event listener to the parent element.

```
$("#card-container").on('submit', '#add-bid', function(event)
```

Here, you bind an event listener to the `#card-container`, which does exist.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, which I needed!

Comment: However, I have a new question: because I can possibly create > 1 cards in the card container, with each card having their own form, do you think there's a way I can make use of this structure to do the submission?

Comment: You already do this, right? You post every form individually with their own data. For an better answer you should create a new question.